# How to wait for all jquery loads to finish

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-deferred

Using Jquery I'm replacing divs that have id's that start with 'lib_' with html from another file.  It all works well, but I need to wait until they are all done before moving on in the code.  The number of divs with 'lib_' could be none, or many. What I have here isn't waiting, it launches LoadStepPart5 before the .load is finished.

```
let deferreds = [];

    $('[id^="lib_"]').each(function(){
        let divID = $(this).attr('id');
        let libID = divID.replace('lib_','');

        deferreds.push( $( '#' + divID ).load( "lib/library.html #" + libID, function(){
            console.log("this appears later, code didn't wait");
        }));
    });

    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
        console.log("immediately displayed");
        LoadStepPart5(n,xml);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.load` follows standard jquery chaining, in that it *returns* the calling selector's jquery object.  eg `$("#id").load("url", callback).show();` will immediately show `#id`.

You are expecting a method that returns a `promise`: `$.ajax`

You can confirm this quickly in the browser console:

```
$("#a").load("url")
n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#a"}

$.ajax({ url: "url" })
{readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

Update your code to:

```
deferreds.push(
    $.ajax(
      { 
        url: "lib/library.html"
      })
      .done(function(html) {
        $("#"+divID).html($("<div>").html(html).find("#"+libID).html());
         console.log("this as html is loaded");
      })
 );
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem and taught me a couple things. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$(window).on('load', function()

{

// code here

});

Comment: If you are using jquery version 1.7 or below you may be like 

$(document).load(function()

{

// code here

});